# How to "delete" words and vowels by moving specific character combinations to an empty array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I'm in an intro C++ class and this assignment is supposed to generate a "variable name" for the user based on a phrase they enter. The program is supposed to replace all spaces with underscores and remove words like "is", "the", "to", etc, as well as vowels. I am stuck on how to remove the specific characters and combination of characters. We are not allowed to use strings and rather are using cstring and and moving parts of the inputted array to the final "variable name" array. This is how I am attempting to do that right now, but it is not working.

```
void remove(char name[21], char copy[21]){//"deletes" or moves filler words and vowels from the inputted phrase

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++){
        if (name[i] == 't'&& name[i + 1] == 'h'&& name[i + 2] == 'e'&& (name [i + 3] == '_' || name[i + 3] == '\0')){
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                copy[i] = name[j];
            }
            for (int j = i + 2; j < strlen(name); j++){
                copy[i] = name[j];
            }
        }

        //and for vowels:    
        else if (toupper(name[i]) == 'A' || toupper(name[i]) == 'E' || toupper(name[i]) == 'I' || toupper(name[i]) == 'O' || toupper(name[i]) == 'U'){
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                copy[i] = name[j];
             }
            for (int j = i; j < strlen(name), j++){
                copy[i] = name[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Some ideas I have are using one of the cstring library functions like strcpy or keeping a count of how many characters beyond "i" you have to go. Also, I'm concerned I'm undoing what I'm doing on a word if there are multiple filler words in the input. All help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: ‘*not allowed to use strings*’  God forbid they should teach C++ at a C++ course.

Comment: @Biffen I'm guessing this is a 1st year BSc assignment, which is C only. I also used to say it's a C++ course, until I started doing actual C++, when I realised the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is homework, I'll try and explain how you should be tackling this problem rather than flat out give a direct solution:

A simple C string copy would look like this:

```
void MyCStringCopy(char* src, char* dst){  
  int i =0;
  while((dst[i]=src[i])!='\0'){i++;}
}
```

A C-string (char*) is essentially an array of chars. src[i] is looking at a specific character in the string. If you loop through the string assigning each character from the source to the destination you will copy the C-string.
The `(src[i]=dst[i])!='\0'` line will satisfy the while loop up until we copy the null (the terminator for C-strings), and the i++ in the loop's body ensures we keep moving through the C-string.
To make a filtered string copy, you'd want to add additional logic before copying. For your purposes, the copy is better written out like this:

```
void MyCStringCopy(char* src, char* dst){  
  int i =0;
  while(1){
    if((dst[i]=src[i])!='\0')
       break;
    i++;
  }
}
```

In your case you are looking for both letter and string matches, so you'll want to loop through each filter term and compare it to the current point in the string before proceeding.

If you find a match between the source string and the filter term you'll want to "skip" forwards that many characters from the source string -- this means your read point and write point will become de-synchronized, and as such you'll want to store them separately.

To compare your filter terms you'll want to use `strncmp(str1,str2,length)` or `strnicmp(str1,str2,length)` (and their family) depending on if you want to be case sensitive or not; it looks like what you have is case in-sensitive, so the second one is the one you'll want. (Warning: strncmp & strnicmp are not portable -- you may have to make your own).

As for replacing characters, I'd do that separately as replacing and removing are different operations, but if you look at how the copy function works you should be able to figure out how to replace one character in a string with another.

If you're really stuck, [here](http://goo.gl/aPqqMS) is a solution in an online compiler. I'd advise you solve this on your own, however.